# decompress gzip compressed data in javascript

Tags: javascript

i am compressing data in gzip format in java like this

```
Object obj = parser.parse(new FileReader("/home/netstorm/FinalFunnelData.json"));
JSONObject jsonObject = (JSONObject) obj;
String data = jsonObject.toJSONString();

ByteOutputStream bos = new ByteOutputStream();

GZIPOutputStream gzip = new GZIPOutputStream(bos);
byte B_ARRAY[] = new byte[1024];
gzip.write(data.trim().getBytes());
gzip.close();
// response.setHeader("Content-Type", "application/json");
//response.setHeader("Content-Encoding", "gzip");
System.out.println(bos.toString());

out.println(bos.toString());
```

but i am unable to decompress it on javascript side?

Comment: You're relying on the browser do decompress it, rather than client-side JavaScript code, right?

Comment: is there any js code to decompress it

Answer (score 1):

The only thing that stands out in your code is :

```
out.println(bos.toString());
```

gzip'ed data is binary, so you cannot treat it as text (`toString()` and `println`).

I'm no Java expert, but you may want to try

```
GZIPOutputStream gzip = new GZIPOutputStream(out);
```

By giving it `out` directly, instead of first putting it in a `ByteOutputStream`, it might just do the right thing.

Comment: i tried with that, but i want code to decompress string js

Comment: how can i convert byte array to string .. i need to send only string data and i m using in jsp , so i cannot use outputstream